# GNU make parse variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to parse variable in makefile, this variable has next syntax:

```
VARIABLE=folder1=file1,folder2=file2,...,folderN=fileN
```

and here what I want to do with it:

```
ifdef VARIABLE
#
# here I want to assign FOLDER to "folder1, folder2... folderN" in the loop
# and then compare it with current folder
#  
ifeq ($(FOLDER),$(CURRENT_FOLDER))
#
# if true assign FILE1=file1 
#
export MYFILE := FILE1
endif
else
export MYFILE = default_name
endif
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the separator `,` to some other, `:` for example

```
VARIABLE=folder1=file1:folder2=file2:...:folderN=fileN
```

you can split the list

```
L=$(subst :, ,$(VARIABLE))
```

extract the folder if any

```
E=$(filter $(CURRENT_FOLDER)=%, $L)
```

and assign the last part after `=` to `MYFILE`

```
ifneq ($E,)
export MYFILE := $(patsubst $(CURRENT_FOLDER)=%,%,$E)
else
export MYFILE = default_name
endif
```

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I'm asking for.